# Changing the location of the database(SQLite) in a jar

Tags: java, sqlite, hibernate, maven, jar

When I create a jar with dependencies from my project (Maven) and run it, the database (SQLite with Hibernate and [SQLite Dialect For Hibernate](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.gwenn/sqlite-dialect)) is stored in the same location as the jar. How can I change the location of the database ?

Snippet from pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Starter</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>./</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Snippet from hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!--SQLite settings-->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:Example.sqlite</property>
    <property name="connection.username"></property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection url property in your hibernate.cfg.xml actually points to the database file. Since you did not specify any path, the current working directory will be used to store/access that file.

It is more a coincidence that you have your working directory the same as the directory holding all your jars.

That said, just put a different connection url and you are done. If you want to determine that at runtime, maybe do not use a hardcoded hibernate.cfg.xml file. You can for sure configure the hibernate session factory through code.